# How to Test an iOS App as if First Time, Each Time?

Tags: ios, testing

Here’s my situation:  I have an iOS app in development.  To thoroughly test each new beta version, especially the content purchase process which happens after the initial app install, I need for my device (iPad) to forget it has already seen and purchased the content of the app before.  Once I purchase, though, each subsequent download automatically activates the previously purchased content, so I don't get to start fresh.

As a solution, I was going through the laborious process of creating a new iTunes account, doing a factory reset on my iPad, adding the new account as a new tester in the iTunes Connect Test Flight system, and testing that way.  It worked a few times.  What I just discovered, though, is that Apple only allows three different accounts to be registered on a single device over the course of a year, so that plan is no longer viable.

My question, then: How are developers testing apps that need to load as if for the first time in a device, after the app has already been perviously loaded and tested?

Stumped on this, appreciate any help.

Cayce

Comment: Yes, it’s a lot simpler on the simulator where you can just erase all settings any time.

Answer (score 1):

The app's data should be deleted by just deleting the app. If it is storing data elsewhere on the device then you can go to Settings-General-Reset-Erase All Content and Settings.
That should do it.